# change background color with a button react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change my view backgroundcolor with a button click. But nothing happens(no error).

```
export default class App extends React.Component{

    state = {
        color: "#fff"
        }

        render() {
            
            return(
                
                <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, flex: 1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',}}>
                  
                  <Button  onClick={() => { this.setState({color: "#00ff00" }) }} title="selam"></Button>

                </View>
                      
            );
        }
};
```

Comment: this code looks find and should work, did you try to change to a color name not hex value like ` color: "red"`

Comment: Yes but thats not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use onPress not onClick

```
<Button onPress={() => { this.setState({color: "#00ff00" }) }} title="selam"></Button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i need to click the button like 8-10 times for the change why?

Comment: i tested and works as expected,maybe your emulator is slow or something it takes time to update

Comment: Yes it was slow now its okey. Thank you so much